# What do the gold wizard's hats do?

Tags: nintendo-ds, lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I have managed to find a couple of golden wizard's hats in various levels of *LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7*. I never manage to find all the ones in a level, though, which made me wonder if they were actually important, and if I should be spending more time looking for them. What do they do?

Comment: It's been awhile, but I don't recall these in the original version (1-4), but do see some references to them on Google in the original version for the DS. So, I wonder if these are DS version specific and made a return in 5-7?

Comment: It is entirely possible. I didn't play the original version, though - so I still have no idea what they do.

Comment: I never saw any Gold Wizard Hats in the Xbox 360 version. What version are you playing? I also don't recall them in _LHP1_.

Comment: @CyberSkull I am playing the Nintendo DS version.

Comment: OK. Those aren't in the home console version then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they unlock still frames of art, which you can access in a particular location in the mission select/hub area.

Answer (score 2):

Finding all of the gold wizard hats in a level opens a "model" in the trophy room at the hub.